# Wordpress custom slug rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have custom post type 'gallery' with the same slug. For other functionality I user `/gallery?tags=snow` and this is ok. I need custom slug like `/gallery-snow` who point on `/gallery?tags=snow`

For example:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_show_var', 0, 1);
function add_show_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'tags';
    return $vars;
}

add_rewrite_rule('^gallery-snow/?$','index.php?post_type=gallery&tags=snow','top');
```

But not working. Any help?

Comment: Can you not just create a taxonomy for your custom post type, then you'll automatically get URLs for all the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find answer

```
add_action('query_vars','foo_set_query_var');
function foo_set_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'tags');
    return $vars;
}

add_rewrite_rule('^gallery-snow/?','index.php?post_type=gallery&tags=snow','top');
```

And in page use

```
get_query_var('tags')
```